# CoreData+NSFetchedResultsController vs sqlite speed

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I got a question about sqlite and I didn't find answer here maybe you can answer me or post an article here and it would be helpful for many other new developers like me.

The question is about speed when using sqlite and CoreData.

When we work with CoreData we can use NSFetchedResultsController and it makes using memory more efficient.

When we work with sqlite there is no such thing as NSFetchedResultsController, and on my mind there are two ways:

1. load all data from sqlite database in viewDidLoad in some array and then use this array in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to display data using indexPath.row as array index - load all data bad idea on my mind
2. get rows count in viewDidLoad to use it in numberOfRowsInSection and then load only needed data in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: using query like this [NSString stringWithFormat: "select id, name from myTable limit 1 offset %d", indexPath.row];

Is way 2 a good idea or making queries to sqlite every single time to display data is a bad idea? If not, which way is faster in use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your data size.

If the size is small, way 1 would be better.

If you have to use sqlite, why not load 30 rows at once time when you can show 20 rows, then when you find the user scroll to row 25, you load another 30 rows. Something like that.

I would prefer Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a sliding array style cache and use a limit other than 1, so that you're not constantly performing fetches.  So that if you ask the cache for a row and it's not there, you read in an N row block in expectation of needing to scroll further.

Or not reinvent CoreData one class at a time, and just use CoreData and the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  :)